# SQL- How to filter registers where date is prior to previous month beginning?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I have this query with a SELECT statement and I need to add to my WHERE clause the condition that the date must be prior to the previous month beginning.

```
SELECT columnA, columnB 
FROM TableX
WHERE columnA=20
```

For example the current date belongs to October so I need to filter the registers where date belongs to September or October from this year.

Let's say we are in December 2022, I would need to filter the registers whose date belongs to November 2022 or December 2022.

I am using an Oracle database.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use the Oracle function SYSDATE to get the current date and then the functions ADD_MONTHS and LAST_DAY (or TRUNC) to get the boundaries for your date range.

Comment: Which is the column storing the date that you're comparing the current date with?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something among the lines of:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB 
  FROM TableX
 WHERE columnA = 20
   AND <your_date_column> BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MM') AND TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE),'MM');
```